# Problem with custom IComparer for List (sort) - c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, ilist, icomparer

can anyone help, i have problem doing a sort, I thought i had it sorted but appears not to be working.

I have a List which stores the following values

8,6,10,11,7

I also have another List (accessories in my class and it has a propert called accessoryId current the classes are in the order of id which is currenty 6,7,8,10,11)

Hence i need to sort them from 6,7,8,10,11 to the order used from the simple list which is 8,6,10,11,7

I have my icomparable (see below) and i am calling like this - it does enter but something is wrong BECAUSE the list still has all my classes but is still in the order of 6,7,8,10,11

```
   // accesories is the IList<Accessories> (hence why i am use ToList)
   // and sortOrder is the simple int list list<int>
   accesories.ToList().Sort(new ItemTpComparer(sortOrder));  

class ItemTpComparer : IComparer<Accessories>
{
    private IList<int> otherList;

    public ItemTpComparer(IList<int> otherList)
    {
        this.otherList = otherList;
    }

    #region IComparer<Accessories> Members

    public int Compare(Accessories x, Accessories y)
    {

        if (otherList.IndexOf(x.AccessoryId) > otherList.IndexOf(y.AccessoryId))
            return 1;

        else if (otherList.IndexOf(x.AccessoryId) < otherList.IndexOf(y.AccessoryId))
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;

        // tried below also didn't work
        //return otherList.IndexOf(x.AccessoryId) - otherList.IndexOf(y.AccessoryId);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comparer is correct (even the commented single line version). The problem is `ToList()` creates a new `List` containing a copy of elements in the `IEnumerable<T>` object so basically, you are creating a new list, sorting it and throwing it away.

```
var sortedList = accesories.ToList();
sortedList.Sort(new ItemTpComparer(sortOrder));
```

for which I'd suggest replacing with:

```
var sortedList = accessories.OrderBy(sortOrder.IndexOf).ToList();
```

this way, no comparer implementation would be necessary. You could also sort in the descending order easily:

```
var sortedList = accessories.OrderByDescending(sortOrder.IndexOf).ToList();
```

If the object is really `List<Accessories>`, you could also sort it in place:

```
((List<Accessories>)accessories).Sort(new ItemTpComparer(sortOrder));
```

Comment: Wow ! thanks thats really good.. i have used "var sortedList = accesories.OrderBy(item => sortOrder.IndexOf(item.AccessoryId)).ToList();"

Also if i provide less numbers for sorting i.e. I provide 8,6 .. and sort .. it works which is great.. what happens is the 8,6 get sorted at the end of the results  ... Is it possible to to sort 8,6 at the beginning and then becuase there is no more sorts .. put the rest in what ever order at the end?

Comment: @mark smith: That's because `IndexOf` will return -1 for non-existent items. I'm updating the answer for the descending sort.

Comment: ah but 1 issue .. the order 8,6 .. and because only 2 are being supplied they end up at the end so doing OrderByDescending reverses them so 8,6 are at the front but the issue is they are reversed as well like 6,8 - any ideas? ... What i trying to say is .. if the sort order is there "do it" and anything after that put at the end

Comment: You could reverse the input `sortOrder` array to solve that problem too.

Comment: If you don't want to use reverse sorting and a reversed sortOrder, there is a solution in my answer...

Comment: Yes .. thank you -   sortOrder  = sortOrder.Reverse().ToList();  . all sorted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Mehrdad showed you why the list was not sorted. I want to address the performance of the comparer, and also the issue with less sorting items than sorted items.

Using IndexOf on a list to locate the index is quite inefficient. I has to loop through the items in the list to find the right one. Use a dictionary as lookup instead, that way you only loop through the items once:

```
class ItemTpComparer : IComparer<Accessories> {

   private Dictionary<int, int> index;

   public ItemTpComparer(IList<int> otherList) {
      index = new Dictionary<int, int>();
      for (int i = 0; i < otherList.Count; i++) {
         index.Add(otherList[i], i);
      }
   }

   public int Compare(Accessories x, Accessories y) {
      return index[x.AccessoryId].CompareTo(index[y.AccessoryId]);
   }

}
```

If you want to allow the list of value to sort by to be shorter than the list of items to sort, you check if the value exists in the dictionary:

```
   public int Compare(Accessories x, Accessories y) {
      int xIndex, yIndex;
      if (!index.TryGetValue(x.AccessoryId, out xIndex)) xIndex = int.MaxValue;
      if (!index.TryGetValue(y.AccessoryId, out yIndex)) yIndex = int.MaxValue;
      return xIndex.CompareTo(yIndex);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you ... much appreciated i taken note .. it may come in handy but currently i am using the lambda stuff as i also need to learn it :-). But thank you

Comment: Note that the lambda solution has the same performance problem, unless you create an index dictionary and use instead of the IndexOf...